# Angular: Get aware of spelling mistakes in function call with ng-click

Tags: angularjs

My question is about discovering possible spelling mistakes in angular expressions, in particular spelling mistakes in the function name.

Consider the snippet bellow:

I have two  buttons there, the first one with correct spelling, the second with a spelling mistake in the angular expression. Clicking the second button does nothing and gives no hints about a potential error.

My question is now: are there ways to detect erroneous calls to function that don't exist (while executing the application)?

I am not looking for some checking possibility in the build or unit test process but rather would like to see a way I could get aware of such a potential issue when running the erroneous expression in the browser when the application is executed.

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("TestController", function($scope){
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
      console.log("Hello World");
    };
  });

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-controller="TestController">
  <button ng-click="myFunction()">myFunction</button>
  <button ng-click="myFunctio()">myFunctio</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with a built in option in angular to do that (using binding to an "undefined" object is a legit UC as things may become "undefined" during program run) - but you may write your own "ng-click" directive which, in case not finding the function to bound to, raise an error (exception or better - console error / warning).

Answer (score 1):

Protractor (and other end to end testing frameworks) will do that for you.

Comment: I am working with dynamically created functions in some cases. For this reason I am looking for something that works at the level of running the application.

Comment: @Sjoerd222888 Actually, this is the case for unit testing, not even e2e (Protractor). If `<button ng-click="myFunctio()">myFunctio</button>` cannot be easily tested, this means that it wasn't designed with TDD in mind in the first place.

Comment: I really like to know how to detect things at runtime with angular. I could create unit-test for all cases because I can resolve what function will be created. But I would really like to know how to detect issues in runtime.

Comment: @Sjoerd222888 then you could use  ` <button ng-click="? myFunction ? myFunctio() : console.log('myFunctio is undefined');">myFunctio</button>` or create your own directives that do the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/40245848/348975 suggests

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the answer? A one-line answer without sufficient explanation is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely common complaint about Angular. Even when writing code for the Closure compiler, with all the type annotations and everything, these still fall right through the cracks.

You can kluge something together, I've seen things like bussing all events to a common broker and looking for the target handler in the bound scope, and so on. But it always appears to be more trouble than it's worth.

Your unit tests are where you catch this sort of thing. It's why being able to test template code via triggering events is such an important thing for an Angular developer to master. If you trigger that button click and your test fails (e.g. your spyOn the handler never gets called), check the template.

Comment: I am working with dynamically created functions in some cases. For this reason I am looking for something that works at the level of running the application.

Comment: I prefer end to end testing over unit tests (as in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40245903/348975), but I don't see why unit tests could not test your dynamically created function.

Comment: I've sat in a number of Angular meetups with the Angular team, and work with the technology every day, and unit tests is always the answer to this question. If you're using some method of dynamically creating functions that can't be tested, you may want to consider adjusting the approach. 

I get that unit tests can be oversold, they're not the answer to everything, you still need E2E. But this is a textbook example of where unit testing can be useful.

Comment: It can be tested of course, but for rapid prototype development it would be nice if this kind of errors pop up while running your development build. And when rapidly building prototypes is not a scenario I want to invest time to write unit-tests. If it becomes a real product, then of course unit-tests are used and we switch to a TDD workflow.

Comment: I completely agree, again this is a hugely complained about shortcoming of working with templates. You can make all kinds of mistakes in them and you get no report at all, it just silently fails.

Comment: (Hit enter too quick): it's one of the pains of working with Angular 1.x (the jury is still out on 2.0), especially where I work. We all joke around about testing directives: "120 lines in the test file, 50 in the directive".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work for function calls or not, but it would solve part of the problem of misspelling something. In Scott Allen's AngularJS Playbook course on Pluralsight, he suggests creating a decorator for the `$interpolate` service to see if any bindings are potentially incorrect. Here is the code for that:

```
(function(module) {

    module.config(function ($provide) {
        $provide.decorator("$interpolate", function ($delegate, $log) {

            var serviceWrapper = function () {
                var bindingFn = $delegate.apply(this, arguments);
                if (angular.isFunction(bindingFn) && arguments[0]) {
                    return bindingWrapper(bindingFn, arguments[0].trim());
                }
                return bindingFn;
            };

            var bindingWrapper = function (bindingFn, bindingExpression) {
                return function () {
                    var result = bindingFn.apply(this, arguments);
                    var trimmedResult = result.trim();
                    var log = trimmedResult ? $log.info : $log.warn;
                    log.call($log, bindingExpression + " = " + trimmedResult);
                    return result;
                };
            };

            angular.extend(serviceWrapper, $delegate);
            return serviceWrapper;

        });
    });

}(angular.module("common")));
```

Comment: How should I use this code? Could not get it to work as expected.

Comment: At the bottom, replace `"common"` with your module name, and it should work for binding misspellings.

Comment: It doesn't work. Interpolation is for templates `{{ }}`, for expressions is used `$parse`.

Comment: It does work for bindings. He can apply a similar decorator concept to `$parse` for misspelled functions.